# Translation for “working-class area”?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Este é o contexto.

> Typical of the Clydeside, Partick is a predominately 'white' working-class area, dominated by tenement housing and home to around 5,000 people.
>
> [Fonte](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=f303BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22working-class%20area%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22working-class%20area%22&f=false)

A minha sugestão para esta tradução seria "área da classe trabalhadora", mas não estou familiarizado com o termo.  Isto está correto para vocês ou teriam uma outra sugestão?

Comment: Seria útil quem votou *close* explicar a sua razão e indicar se acha que é possível melhorar a pergunta. Spohreis, eu acho que podes realmente melhorar a pergunta, nomeadamente podes indicar as traduções que já consideraste e por que razão elas não são satisfatórias. Dá uma vista de olhos pelas perguntas com tag "tradução" e "tradução-inglês".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Além da já referida *classe proletária*, poderia ser *zona operária* se os membros da classe trabalhadora que nela moram forem predominantemente operários. Se não o forem, eu traduziria por *zona de casas/apartamentos* (modestas/os) *da classe trabalhadora* ou *zona de casas/apartamentos da classe baixa*. Neste contexto julgo ser preferível usar *zona* em vez de *área*.

Após ler a fonte citada, a minha tradução seria *zona operária*, já que Partick,  em Cliveside, é uma zona que sofreu um processo de desindustrializacão.

Nota final: a versão portuguesa da página da Wikipedia [*working class*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_class) é [*classe trabalhadora*](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_trabalhadora).

Comment: wordreference: 'working-class' found in these entries
In the English description:
common people - common stock - commoner - lower classes - prole - proletariat

Answer (score 3):

*Proletária* seria uma boa opção.